# Visual studion 2013 MVC5 (Getting error in reading app.config value of portable class library)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Visual studion 2013 MVC5 (Getting error in reading app.config value of portable class library). I have two project

1. Web application
2. Portable Class Library.

I have used key values in app.config of Class Library project which I want 
to read in my class file but as System.Configuration class is not available in Library project so I am not able to read values from app.config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="xyz" value="123" />
</appSettings>
```

When I tried to read value in one of the class file of class library as

```
public class mytest
{
  public static string AppValue=
      System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xyz"].ToString();
}
```

I got the error as `The 'configuration' element is not declared` when I tried to using System.Configuration, I didn't get this in class library.

Comment: You might be missing assembly referrance for `System.Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that below configuration available on your **webconfig** file

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="xyz" value="123" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I have 2 projects in my solution one is web application which includes web.config file and another portable class library project which includes app.config file, I want to read key values from app.config file in on of my class file of class library.I have to added <appSettings> in my app.config file which is in my class library project, I do have added reference of this class library project in my web application as well.

Comment: @user4327298 - `app.config` files for class libraries are ignored. The only config file that is automatically read into the configuration classes is the one for the main EXE of an application or the `web.config` file for a web project.